# macros autofilter not working

Tags: vba, autofilter

The following program is showing error message "*'AutoFilter' method of Range class failed*", and I am not able to find the solution for this:

```
Sub filterforaging()

' filterforaging Macro
'

'
    Columns("i:i").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        ">10 days", "5-8days", "8-10days"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't apply autofilters with `Rows("1:1")` selected. Try selecting `Range("A1")` instead. Or better, [don't select anything](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513).

Answer (score 2):

First off `">10 days"` must be `"*>10 days"`, to (I guess) avoid the `">"` part to lead to a *comparison* criteria

But then again there remains a weird behavior related to `"*>10 days"` filter:

- if you filter by it alone

  ```
  .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*>10 days"
  ```

  it would correctly filter the wanted rows
- if you filter by it and another value only

  ```
  .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*>10 days", "8-10days"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  ```

  it would still work correctly
- **but if you filter by it and another two values**

  ```
  .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*>10 days", "5-8days", "8-10days"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  ```

  **then it would only filter the other two values**

As to now I could only get to the following workaround:

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$10000")
    .Rows(1).AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*>10 days"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) - 1 > 0 Then Set rng1 = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("5-8days", "8-10days"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) - 1 > 0 Then Set rng2 = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    .AutoFilter
    .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then rng1.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then rng2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was perfect,

Comment: @Nagarjun, glad to know that. Then please mark answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you